# Visual Studio hangs for 20 seconds before start building

Tags: visual-studio, time, build

I've got a problem with the visual studio 2010 and the building time of one project (VB.net). I would say the project is large for just one DLL so I could understand when the building time itself lasts a little bit longer then on other projects.

But the weird thing is: When I start building, the following line shows up on the output window:
------ Build started: Project: kaCtrl, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------

And then it looks like the compiler is doing nothing. Even if I change the output option to "diagnostic" to see every step in the building process, just nothing happens. After 20 seconds the build starts and is finished in 1 second.

But what the heck is the visual studio doing in this 20 seconds? Is there anything I can disable to make it faster?

Comment: Yes, it happens, it has happened with all previous VS versions too. VS seems to asking itself philosophical questions before continuing.

Comment: If you're concerned about the delay that Visual Studio is introducing why don't you remove it from the equation? See command-line options here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25fz1td5.aspx

Comment: Hmmm okay, thank your for your answers. Well command-line isn't a option for me because of debuging etc. I really wonder what VS is doing in this time. It's just annyoing!

Answer (score 0):

I too had this problem, when I analysed this problem I figured out that it was eating too much CPU memory (checked in task manager-> performance) during this time.So what I did to make it faster was, I stopped some unnecessary services (which consume some specific amount of cpu memory) like office, adobe, etc and closed all other apps other then vs2010 and executed my commands. Magic happened. It build in 5 seconds approximately. Not sure whether it will work out for you or not but definitely worth a chance. All thee best